# json_encode() doesn't work with webhook model in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, webhooks

I handle a webhook with spatie package. Everything going well but when I try to get the data from the payload like they says in spatie doc with :

```
// you can access the payload of the webhook call with `$webhookCall->payload`
```

and I try to use the data like a JSON object like this :

```
$payload = $webhookCall->payload;

       // Handle the event
        switch ($payload->type) {
            case 'checkout.session.completed':
                $sessions = $payload->data->object; 
                SubscriptionController::handle_checkout_session($sessions);
                break;
            case 'checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded':
                $paymentSuccess = $payload->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
                // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
                // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
                break;
            case 'customer.created':
                $customer = $payload->data->object;
            break;
                // ... handle other event types
            default:
                // Unexpected event type
                http_response_code(400);
                exit();
        }

        http_response_code(200);
    }
```

I've a exception :

```
local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'type' of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'type' of non-object at /var/www/private/bnb-v2/bnb-back/app/Listeners/HandleSubscriptions.php:29)
```

I try to use

```
$payload = json_encode($webhookCall->payload)
```

because when I watch in the WebHookCall model :

```
protected $casts = [
        'payload' => 'array',
        'exception' => 'array',
    ];
```

but I get a other exception :

```
Expected type 'object'. Found 'string|false'
```

I don't know what can I do...

Thanks a lot...

[EDIT]

If I use :

```
Log:info($payload);
```

I get :

```
[2020-06-10 23:54:42] local.INFO: array (
  'id' => 'evt_1GsdhqLGS8lOFak768TAN8re',
  'object' => 'event',
  'api_version' => '2019-12-03',
  'created' => 1591833101,
  'data' => 
  array (
    'object' => 
    array (
      'id' => 'cs_test_G0hfQI1fJb4DdMReZLjO6P9RVLPmls9uZvBox0oDDfkMyk2bKTShztfE',
      'object' => 'checkout.session',
      'billing_address_collection' => NULL,
      'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
      'client_reference_id' => NULL,
      'customer' => 'cus_HRWl1LPRMBwlsf',
      'customer_email' => NULL,
      'livemode' => false,
      'locale' => NULL,
      'metadata' => 
      array (
      ),
      'mode' => 'subscription',
      'payment_intent' => NULL,
      'payment_method_types' => 
      array (
        0 => 'card',
      ),
      'setup_intent' => NULL,
      'shipping' => NULL,
      'shipping_address_collection' => NULL,
      'submit_type' => NULL,
      'subscription' => 'sub_HRWl7thLXiPC5c',
      'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    ),
  ),
  'livemode' => false,
  'pending_webhooks' => 3,
  'request' => 
  array (
    'id' => NULL,
    'idempotency_key' => 'pi_1GsdheLGS8lOFak7SUFO7VFk-src_1GsdheLGS8lOFak7nFe7hElv',
  ),
  'type' => 'checkout.session.completed',
)
```

If I use :

```
$payload = json_encode($webhookCall->payload)
```

I get in my log :

```
[2020-06-11 07:48:22] local.INFO: {"id":"evt_1Gsl95LGS8lOFak7Spk01sPF","object":"event","api_version":"2019-12-03","created":1591861699,"data":{"object":{"id":"cs_test_mzoAOmE7UsuOGCbC3mrssVkGFqpUuYEkganGXOY59bW77mGFdVTrlJmP","object":"checkout.session", "billing_address_collection":null,"cancel_url":"https:\/\/example.com\/cancel","client_reference_id":null,"customer":"cus_HReRkIznmhyycg","customer_email":null,"livemode":false, "locale":null,"metadata":{},"mode":"subscription","payment_intent":null,"payment_method_types":{"0":"card"}, "setup_intent":null,"shipping":null,"shipping_address_collection":null,"submit_type":null,"subscription":"sub_HReRDcbQY6YEsZ","success_url":"https:\/\/example.com\/success"}},"livemode":false,"pending_webhooks":3,"request":{"id":null,"idempotency_key":"pi_1Gsl8xLGS8lOFak7amco9m0o-src_1Gsl8xLGS8lOFak7YjGswFWC"},"type":"checkout.session.completed"}
```

So its a an object, no ?

But I get the exception :

```
2020-06-11 07:48:22] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'type' of non-object 
{"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'type' of non-object at /var/www/private/bnb-v2/bnb-back/app/Listeners/HandleSubscriptions.php:33)
```

I don't understand...

Comment: dd($payload); it might be null or encoded object.

Comment: I can't use dd() function because I'm in listener when i want use the webhook... @ITDesigns.eu

Comment: then just use `info();` or similar....

Comment: But where I can see the info ?

Comment: in your log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your returned $payload is array, you have to use it accordingly:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$payload = $webhookCall->payload;
$type = Arr:get($payload, 'type');
$object = Arr:get($payload, 'data.object');

// Handle the event
switch ($type) {
    case 'checkout.session.completed':
        $sessions = $object; 
        SubscriptionController::handle_checkout_session($sessions);
        break;
    case 'checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded':
        $paymentSuccess = $object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
        // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
    case 'customer.created':
        $customer = $object;
        break;
        // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}

http_response_code(200);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution ! ;) Finally, I use it like a array but I would know why I can access to the data like a JSON object after a json_encode() ?

Comment: json_encode converts to string... Did you mean json_decode?

Comment: I would have to see more of your code, but the reason may be that you casting to `array`, not `object`. Or that your `json_decode`, if you are really using it, is set with `$assoc` set to `true`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php